# getting D3.js to display using container

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a novice d3.js question. I have tried entering a lot of tutorial inputs but I can never seem to get the display output working. Here's one example. I have a d3.js page template example (from Scott Murray's D3 book.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Your beautiful D3 code will go here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So now, I go to: http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/ and try to enter the first code example in the D3 container:

```
var rectDemo = d3.select("#rect-demo").
  append("svg:svg").
  attr("width", 400).
  attr("height", 300);

rectDemo.append("svg:rect").
  attr("x", 100).
  attr("y", 100).
  attr("height", 100).
  attr("width", 200);
```

I have scoured the Web searching for sources on exactly how to structure your D3 code within an html file, but unfortunately almost all of the tutorials assume that you'll know where to place the relevant code lines to make it all work when you open your browser. This general problem has plagued me for the past several weeks, in getting off the ground.

When I entered the above in the container, I got no output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Your beautiful D3 code will go here
            // http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/
            var rectDemo = d3.select("#rect-demo").
              append("svg:svg").
              attr("width", 400).
              attr("height", 300);

            rectDemo.append("svg:rect").
              attr("x", 100).
              attr("y", 100).
              attr("height", 100).
              attr("width", 200);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain briefly why this is, and what I have to do, to get this example to display? Many thanks! I've been working all day on trying to get examples to show up and minor modifications I try to make, make any example output that's copied and pasted, disappear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is really just the inital "entry point", i.e. the element that D3 appends everything to. In your HTML template, you have nothing in the body of the element, but in the D3 code, you're selecting the element with ID "rect-demo" to append everything to. This element doesn't exist, and therefore nothing happens.

So you have two choices to make this work -- either add an element with this ID to your HTMl template, or tell D3 to append to the `body`.

Option 1:

```
<body>
<div id="rect-demo"></div>
// etc
```

Option 2:

```
var rectDemo = d3.select("body").
// etc
```

On a general note, with the latest version of D3, you don't need to specify the namespace for the added elements explicitly (except in cases where it's ambiguous). That is, instead of `.append("svg:rect")` you can simply do `.append("rect")`.

Comment: Thanks - I implemented Option 2 and it works! One brief followup question -- I noticed that in the div id I have "rect-demo", and in the script container, d3.select("#rect-demo") -- I toggled the # sign on and off, and it's a necessary component to have to get a display in the Chrome browser. Do I have to do this with similar div ids that I will refer to, in the script body?

Comment: ^ Yes. Basically d3 uses a jQuery style query selector syntax; so #id refers to an element with an id of 'id', .class refers to an element with a class of 'class', etc. It might be easier for you to go with option 1 and append the D3 instance to an element with an ID you can control, this way you can have multiple instances of D3 in the page without any problems. :)

Comment: The `#` is a marker that you're referencing the ID of the element. Similarly, `.` marks a class, so if you want to select everything of class `foobar`, you would do `d3.selectAll(".foobar")`.

Comment: @Ben, there's not necessarily a problem with running D3 in this case. What would happen is that several SVGs would be appended to the page, but there wouldn't be any interference.

Comment: Sure, but this way you have more control over the structure of the page instead of appending D3 elements on a first come first served basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, you'll need to run the file on a local server. If you're using a Mac, an Apache server is built in, or you can get something like [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html), or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for Windows. I noticed though that Firefox renders D3 using `file://` URLs so that would be the quickest fix; just use Firefox. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried running it on Firefox but it also won't display. Also, I should point out that other D3.js examples I have, have gotten to display in Chrome (what I normally use), so there seems to be something about this structure that is off. There is a reference to "To produce this with D3, add a container div to the page" but I thought that you're supposed to put D3 code into the slot created in the template, and I'm not sure whether the existing container in the template is a type of div container or not...